# How to remove a feature in openlayers with multiple possible sources

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-5

I have a map with multiple layers, all connected to different vector sources.

When a user selects a feature I want him to be able to delete the feature. However, I can't seem to find a way to locate the source layer the feature is from.

If I try to just remove the feature from all layers I get an error:

```
Vector.js:946 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at Vector.removeFeatureInternal (Vector.js:946)
```

Is there a good way of doing finding the source layer or removing features without specifying from where?

At the moment I'm catching the exceptions, but this turns unwieldy with a lot of layers and sources.

Comment: How does your select interaction look like?

Comment: The select feature is just taken from one of the exmples:

  const select = new Select({
    wrapX: false
});

and added to the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each source, you could try to get the selected Feature. If the response is not `null`, the feature exists on that source.
Something along this way inside your select:

```
const featureId = selectedFeature.getId()
map.getLayers().getArray().forEach(layer => {
  const source = layer.getSource();
  if (source instanceof VectorLayer) {
    const featureExists = source.getFeatureById(featureId);
    if (featureExists) {
      source.removeFeature(selectedFeature);
      return;
    }
  }
})
```